# AVAudioSession output selection

Tags: ios7, avfoundation, core-audio, audiounit, avaudiosession

If multiple input & output accessories are attached to iPhone, I want the user to be able to manually select the input & output source. I can manually select input by querying [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs] and then using setPreferredInput:error method in iOS 7, but I can not find anything similar for output. How do I achieve this ? I am using PlayAndRecord category.

Answer (score 1):

Apple don't want developers to change the output route/volume programmically. Maybe MPVolumeView is your choice.

Add a MPVolumeView, and then set its showsRouteButton to YES.

[The Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/index.html) says, "The route button is visible by default when there is more than one audio output route available."

Like this:
[image: MPVolumeView example]

Edit:
Although Apple don't want developers to change output route programically, sometimes we can still change output route forcefully when iPhone is not connected to headset/headphone:

```
AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];
```

this takes effect only when iPhone is not connected to headset/headphone.

Answer (score -1):

You can get available outputs by calling [output​Data​Sources](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616479-outputdatasources) and change it using [set​Output​Data​Source](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616582-setoutputdatasource).

Comment: "This feature is supported only on certain USB accessories." This doesn't sound very promising.

Comment: Incorrect answer -- this is for switching between outputs *on a single peripheral* after you have already set the audio routing, e.g. a device that has both front and back speakers.